# Two-headed arrow and continuous straight arrow in xy package

Tags: xy-pic

Using xy package, I have produced a figure. But I have a problem:

How can one create an arrow or a two-headed arrow between the two entries of a matrix that are located in different columns in which the difference of the columns' numbers are strictly greater than one(e.g. column number 1 and column number 3) in xy package? (In fact, I intend to have a continuous straight arrow between the two boxes in line 5 of the following flow chart instead of the two represented arrows).

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\oddsidemargin=.25cm \evensidemargin=.25cm \textwidth=15cm
\topmargin=0cm \textheight=21cm
\begin{document}
\title{Graphical Abstract}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[!h]
\small
{\[\xymatrix{
\framebox[0.33\textwidth]{\textbf{Partition of Unity}\quad \textbf{\&}\ar[d] \quad \textbf{State}}  & &  \framebox[0.42\textwidth]{\textbf{State}\quad \textbf{\&} \quad \textbf{Hyper Injective Mapping}} \ar[d] \\
\framebox[0.36\textwidth]{\textbf{Entropy of a Partition of Unity}}\ar[d] \ar[r] & \ar[d]  & \framebox[0.45\textwidth]{\textbf{Hyper Injective Hyper $MV$--Algebra DS}} \ar[l] \\
\framebox[0.2\textwidth]{\textbf{Properties}} \ar[d] & \framebox[0.2\textwidth]{h(T, U)} \ar[d] \ar[r] \ar[l] & \framebox[0.2\textwidth]{\textbf{Calculations}} \ar[d] \\
\framebox[0.3\textwidth]{\textbf{Theorem of Isomorphism}} \ar[r] & \framebox[0.2\textwidth]{h(T)} \ar[ul] \ar[ur] \ar[l] \ar[r] & \framebox[0.32\textwidth]{\textbf{Kolmogorov-Sinai Theorem}} \ar[l] \\
\framebox[0.45\textwidth]{\textbf{Hyper Injective Hyper $MV$--Algebra DS}} \ar[dr] & \ar[r] \ar[l] & \framebox[0.48\textwidth]{\textbf{Semi-Independent Hyper $MV$--Algebra DS}} \ar[dl] \\
& \framebox[0.2\textwidth]{\textbf{$MV$--Algebra DS}} \ar[ul] \ar[ur]& }
\]}
\caption{\label{1}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `newlfont` package has become obsolete in 1995.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do an arrow over two columns which would be `\ar[rr]` seeing from the left node. Than you have to change the arrow heads of this arrow which would look like `\ar@{<->}[rr]`. This should solve your problem.

```
% arara: pdflatex    

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}

\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\calclayout

\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}
    }

\begin{document}
    \title{Graphical Abstract}
    \maketitle
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \[
        \xymatrix@C=-.2em{%
            \fbox{\bfseries Partition of Unity \& State} \ar[d] & & \fbox{\bfseries State \& Hyper Injective Mapping} \ar[d] \\
            \fbox{\textbf{\specialcell{Entropy of a Partition\\ of Unity}}} \ar[d] \ar[r] & \ar[d]  & \fbox{\textbf{\specialcell{Hyper Injective Hyper\\ $MV$--Algebra DS}}} \ar[l] \\
            \fbox{\textbf{Properties}} \ar[d] & \fbox{$h(T, U)$} \ar[d] \ar[r] \ar[l] & \fbox{\textbf{Calculations}} \ar[d] \\
            \fbox{\textbf{Theorem of Isomorphism}} \ar@{<->}[r] & \fbox{$h(T)$} \ar[ul] \ar[ur] \ar@{<->}[r] & \fbox{\textbf{Kolmogorov-Sinai Theorem}} \\
            \fbox{\textbf{\specialcell{Hyper Injective Hyper\\ $MV$--Algebra DS}}} \ar@{<->}[dr]\ar@{<->}[rr] & & \fbox{\textbf{\specialcell{Semi-Independent Hyper\\ $MV$--Algebra DS}}} \ar@{<->}[dl] \\
            & \fbox{\textbf{$MV$--Algebra DS}} & 
        }
        \]
        \caption{}\label{1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Such things are much easier done with Ti*k*Z. If you want to do that in a similar matrix syntax, you might want to take a look on [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd):

```
% arara: pdflatex    

\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzcd}[%
        ,cells={%
            ,nodes={%
                ,draw
                ,align=center
                ,font=\bf
                ,outer sep=1mm
                }
            }
        ,column sep={13em,between origins}  
        ]
            Partition of Unity \& State\ar[d] & & State \& Hyper Injective Mapping\ar[d] \\
            \specialcell{Entropy of a Partition\\ of Unity}\ar[d] \ar[to path={-|(\tikztotarget)}]{dr} &  & \specialcell{Hyper Injective Hyper\\ $MV$--Algebra DS}\ar[to path={-|(\tikztotarget)}]{dl} \\
            Properties\ar[d] & $h(T, U)$\ar[d] \ar[r] \ar[l] & Calculations\ar[d] \\
            Theorem of Isomorphism\ar[<->]{r} & $h(T)$\ar[ul] \ar[ur] \ar[<->]{r} & Kolmogorov-Sinai Theorem\\
            \specialcell{Hyper Injective Hyper\\ $MV$--Algebra DS}\ar[<->]{dr}\ar[<->]{rr} & & \specialcell{Semi-Independent Hyper\\ $MV$--Algebra DS}\ar[<->]{dl} \\
            & $MV$--Algebra DS& 
    \end{tikzcd}
    \caption{}\label{1}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just as an aside, `amsart` has its own method for setting page dimensions: `\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}\calclayout`

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I've never used this class before. Please feel free to revise my edit.

Comment: You just set the desired height and width; then `\calclayout` recomputes `\topmargin`, `\oddsidemargin` and so on.